# XAML Theme Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, themes

I'm looking for a XAML theme that resembles the light theme of Visual Studio 2012.  Does anything like this ship with the IDE or is there a way to generate one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) project has a theme that looks like Visual Studio. It is the dark theme but I think it shouldn't be too much work to change the colors to the light theme.

Take a look at the demo application and the [documentation](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/).